# Javascript: best way to instantiate an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

What is the easiest was to populate an array with a large number of objects created with a constructor?

I have a constructor function than makes TV and movie objects:

```
function Media(name, boxCover) {
    this.name = name;
    this.boxCover = boxCover;
};
```

I am making many objects that I want to put into an array. This does not work:

```
var table = [
var avengers = new Media("avengers",'../assets/boxcovers/avengers.jpg');
var blade_runner = new Media("blade_runner",'../assets/boxcovers/blade_runner.jpg');
var brave = new Media("brave",'../assets/boxcovers/brave.jpg');
var catching_fire = new Media("catching_fire",'../assets/boxcovers/catching_fire.jpg');
var django = new Media("django",'../assets/boxcovers/django.jpg');
var finding_nemo = new Media("finding_nemo",'../assets/boxcovers/finding_nemo.jpg');
];
```

I also tried putting `table.push(` at the beginning of each line.  Do I really need to list each object *again* in the array like this or I can save the duplicate effort:

```
table = [avengers, blade_runner, etc.
```

Comment: You have to separate the variable declarations and array initialiser, you can't do both in one statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for this would be

```
var table = {
    mykey: myproperty,
    mykey2: myproperty2
};
```

If you want your variable to be an object, that is you can access properties by calling f.e `table.avengers`, your declaration should look like:

```
var table = {
    avengers: new Media("avengers",'../assets/boxcovers/avengers.jpg'),
    blade_runner: new Media("blade_runner",'../assets/boxcovers/blade_runner.jpg'),
    brave: new Media("brave",'../assets/boxcovers/brave.jpg')
    //... and so on and so forth
};
```

If you only want to be able to loop through them, you can create it as an array:

```
var table = [
    new Media("avengers",'../assets/boxcovers/avengers.jpg'),
    new Media("blade_runner",'../assets/boxcovers/blade_runner.jpg'),
    new Media("brave",'../assets/boxcovers/brave.jpg')
    //... and so on and so forth
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax. Try this instead:

```
function Media(name, boxCover) {
    this.name = name;
    this.boxCover = boxCover;
};

var table = [
 new Media('avengers','../assets/boxcovers/avengers.jpg'),
 new Media('blade_runner','../assets/boxcovers/blade_runner.jpg')         
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple syntax also such as:

```
var mediatable = [];
var entry = {
    name: {},
    boxCover: {}
};
mediatable.push({
    name: "avengers",
    boxCover: '../assets/boxcovers/avengers.jpg'
});
mediatable.push({
    name: "blade_runner",
    boxCover: '../assets/boxcovers/blade_runner.jpg'
});
alert(mediatable.length);
```

or push it using the object:

```
entry.name = "brave";
entry.boxCover = '../assets/boxcovers/brave.jpg';
mediatable.push(entry);
alert(mediatable.length + ":" + mediatable[1].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Media(name, boxCover) {
    this.name = name;
    this.boxCover = boxCover;
};

function MediaTable(data) {
    var table = {};
    data.forEach(function(el){
        table[el[0]] = new Media(el[0], el[1])
    })

    return table;
};

var tableData = [
        ["avengers", '../assets/boxcovers/avengers.jpg'],
        ["blade_runner", '../assets/boxcovers/blade_runner.jpg'],
        ["brave" , '../assets/boxcovers/brave.jpg'],
        ["catching_fire", '../assets/boxcovers/catching_fire.jpg'],
        ["django", '../assets/boxcovers/django.jpg'],
        ["finding_nemo", '../assets/boxcovers/finding_nemo.jpg']
    ],
    table = new MediaTable(tableData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite your **var table** like this, that's all needed:

```
var table = [
  new Media("avengers",'../assets/boxcovers/avengers.jpg'),
  new Media("blade_runner",'../assets/boxcovers/blade_runner.jpg'),
  new Media("brave",'../assets/boxcovers/brave.jpg'),
  new Media("catching_fire",'../assets/boxcovers/catching_fire.jpg'),
  new Media("django",'../assets/boxcovers/django.jpg'),
  new Media("finding_nemo",'../assets/boxcovers/finding_nemo.jpg')
];
```